# действие при сабмите формы на сервере

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submit

Доброго времени суток! Я новичок, с `js` на Вы, с `ajax` впервые встретился лицом к лицу.

Задача передо мной стоит следующая: чатбот в попапе общается с посетителем сайта, при сабмите формы (отправка сообщения от пользователя) каждый раз передаются данные на сервер (сообщение соответственно попадает в окошко чата). Пока тестил локально - всё было ок. Но загрузив на сервер столкнулся с проблемой: после сабмита формы открывается страница ошибки.

Имею следующий код:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    function AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: JSON.stringify(someJSON),

//          success: function(response) {

//               smth

//          },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log('wtf');
            }
        });
    }

    $("#chatbot-submit").click(
        function(){
            AjaxFormRequest();
//                return false;

        }

    );
});
```

Пока строка
`//            return false;`
закомментирована - выбрасывает на 404, если раскомментировать - форма не сабмитится. Мне необходимо, чтоб данные отправлялись при сабмите, но страница не перезагружалась.

разметка формы примитивная

```
<form action="/algo/bookChat.php" method="post" id="chatform">
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="chatbot-input" type="text" name="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сообщение и нажмите Enter..." autocomplete="off" required>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <input id="chatbot-submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `someJSON`? `AjaxFormRequest();` - оба параметра `undefined`. `return false;` - уместен.

Comment: @Igor буду благодарен за разъяснение, как правильно написать параметры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы не переходило на другую страницу используйте [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
 $("#chatbot-submit").click(
      function( $event ){

          AjaxFormRequest(/*тут нехватает данных и урла*/);
          $event.preventDefault();
          return false; //тоже можно, данные не отсылаются не из-за этого
      }
  );
```

Форма не отправляется (когда ракоменнтировываете `return false`) из-за того что вы ничего не передаёте в AjaxFormRequest.

```
function AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) { //требуется 2 параметра
                                         // судя по названию это данные и куда передавать

  jQuery.ajax({
      url: url, //неопределена, в клике вы вызываете ajaxFormRequest без параметров
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      data: JSON.stringify(someJSON), // someJSON неопределена (всегда)

      error: function(response) {
          console.log('wtf');
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: буду благодарен, если подскажете, где найти информацию о передаваемых параметрах. Мне необходимо передавать данные, которые я собираю в переменную someJSON

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  function AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      data: formData,
      //success: function(response) {
      //  smth
      //},
      error: function(response) {
        console.log("Error: " + response);
      }
    });
  }

  $("#chatbot-submit").click(function() {
    AjaxFormRequest($("#chatform").serialize(), $("#chatform").attr("action"));
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Вы указали 
data: formData,
но мне необходимо json массив, который находится в переменной someJSON

Comment: В Вашем коде переменная `someJSON` встречается один раз, и откуда она берется непонятно. Зачем здесь вообще форма? Если Вам в ajax'е не нужны данные из формы - уберите первый параметр в `AjaxFormRequest`.

Comment: из формы будет браться только содержимое инпута при отправке.
а в переменную будут передаваться следующие данные:

var messages = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('chatbot-message').querySelectorAll('.from-user'));
        var lastMsg = document.getElementById('chatbot-input').value;
        var someJSON = messages.map(
                (msgBlock) => {
                return msgBlock.textContent.replace('Вы: ', '')
            })

Comment: написал весь код в топике 
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551850/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-ajax-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5