# Проблема с ajax на сервере

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

Доброго времени суток! Я начинающий фронт. С аяксоми первый раз работаю, прошу помощи в разъяснении, гугл не выручил(
имею следующую задачу. при клике на кнопку всплывает попап, в котором находится окошко чата с одним инпутом. Пользователь строит диалог с ботом и при каждом сабмите формы данные должны аяксом отправляться на сервер. Писал всё локально, без сервера, работает, сообщения в чатик поступают. Но как залил на сервер при сабмите происходит переход на 404, либо вообще не сабмитится, если использовать event.preventDefault();
Прошу подсказать, как указать правильные параметры в функции для передачи на сервер и как сделать, чтоб код работал как на локальной машине.

---

код функции для отправки данных на сервер:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
function AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) {
    var messages = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('chatbot-message').querySelectorAll('.from-user'));
    var lastMsg = document.getElementById('chatbot-input').value;
    var filteredMessages = messages.map(
        (msgBlock) => {
        return msgBlock.textContent.replace('Вы: ', '')
        };
    )

    console.log(filteredMessages);
    console.log(lastMsg);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: JSON.stringify(filteredMessages + ' , ' + lastMsg)
    });
}

$("#chatbot-submit").click(
    function () {
        AjaxFormRequest(formData, url);
        return false;
    }
);
```

});

---

код целиком:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Annoying Chatbot
  //==================================================================================================================

  $('#chatbot').on('click', '#chatbot-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    message = $('#chatbot-input').val();
    message = message.toLowerCase();
    sendMessage();
    bot(message);
    clearInterval(botAuto);
  });

  function botAutoMessage() {
    var messageArray = [
      'Вы ещё здесь?',
      'Вы на связи?',
      '?'
    ];

    sendMessage(messageArray);
  }

  var botAuto = setInterval(botAutoMessage, 30000);

  function bot(message) {
    if (message.indexOf('здравствуйте') >= 0) {

      var messageArray = [
        'Hello to you too!',
        'I said hello first :)',
        'Greeting, human.'
      ];

      sendMessage(messageArray);
    }

    // else if (message.indexOf('good morning') >= 0) {
    //
    //     var messageArray = [
    //         'Good morning to you too. How are you this morning?',
    //         'Yeah, its good ',
    //         'Greeting, human.'
    //     ];
    //
    //     sendMessage(messageArray);
    // }
    else if (message == '') {

      var messageArray = [
        'Вы прислали пустое сообщение',
        'Вы не ввели данных'
      ];

      sendMessage(messageArray);
    } else {

      var messageArray = [
        'blablabla',
      ];

      sendMessage(messageArray);

    }
  }

  // scroll to the bottom of chat box
  function scrollToMessage() {
    var msgBox = $('#chatbot-message');
    var height = msgBox[0].scrollHeight;
    msgBox.scrollTop(height);
  }

  // sending message
  function sendMessage(message) {
    if (message) {

      $('#chatbot-input').addClass('disabled');
      $('#chatbot-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#chatbot-submit').addClass('disabled');
      $('#chatbot-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

      var respond = message[Math.floor(Math.random() * message.length)];

      setTimeout(function() {
        botPre = '<span class="message">Врач печатает сообщение... <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>';
        botVal = respond;
        botMessage = $('#chatbot-message').html() + '<br><p class="from-bot"><span class="user">Врач: </span>' + botPre + '</p>';
        $('#chatbot-input').attr('placeholder', 'Врач печатает сообщение...');
        $('#chatbot-message').html(botMessage);
        scrollToMessage();
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        botMessageReplace = $('#chatbot-message .from-bot:last-child()');
        botMessage = '<span class="user">Врач: </span>' + botVal;
        $('#chatbot-input').attr('placeholder', 'Введите сообщение...');
        botMessageReplace.html(botMessage);
        scrollToMessage();
        $('#chatbot-input').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#chatbot-input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#chatbot-submit').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#chatbot-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }, 2800);

    } else {

      userVal = $('#chatbot-input').val();
      userMessage = $('#chatbot-message').html() + '<br><p class="from-user"><span class="user">Вы: </span><span class="message">' + userVal + '</span></p>';
      $('#chatbot-message').html(userMessage);
      scrollToMessage();
      $('#chatbot-input').val('');

    }

  }

  // time
  var date = new Date();
  var now = (date.getHours() + '.' + date.getMinutes());
});
```

```css
#main-demo-body {
  margin: 30px auto 100px;
  width: 600px
}
#main-demo-body * {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
.demo-widget {
  margin: 0 auto 30px
}
.demo-widget .demo-widget-header {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #115c89;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f9fc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.9px 5px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.28);
}
.demo-widget-header__img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.demo-widget-header__title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.demo-widget .demo-widget-body {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}
.demo-widget .demo-widget-body .form-group:last-of-type {
  margin: 0
}
#chatbot-message p:nth-child(2n+1) {
  /*float: right;*/
  padding: 10px;
  /*background-color: #d3ebff;*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.9px 5px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.28);
}
#chatbot-message p:nth-child(2n) {
  /*float: left;*/
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f4f9fc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.9px 5px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.28);
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message {
  padding: 0;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3f3f3f;
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message p:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message p.from-bot {
  /*color: #0af;*/
  background-color: #f4f9fc;
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message p.from-user {
  float: right;
  background-color: #d3ebff;
  /*color: #0af*/
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message p.from-bot .user {
  /*color: #0af*/
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message p:nth-child(even) {
  /*background-color: #d3ebff;*/
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message .user {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message .message {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #bfbfbf
}
#chatbot #chatbot-message .message .glyphicon {
  font-size: 10px
}
#chatbot .input-group-btn .btn {
  border-left: 0
}
.input-group {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 4px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  padding: 13px;
}
.input-group > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.input-group input {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px;
  /*width: 80%;*/
  width: 484px;
  height: 33px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn {
  width: 65px;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn input {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent url(../img/submit-chat.png) no-repeat center center;
  width: 43px;
  height: 33px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop-up fpopup">
  <div id="main-demo-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="demo-widget">
        <div class="demo-widget-header">
          <div class="photo-doctor-popup">
            <?if(!empty($cli)):?>
              <img src="<?=$cli['logo']?>" alt="" />
              <?else:?>
                <img src="<?=($doc['avatar'])? $doc['avatar'] : '/img/nophoto.png'?>" alt="" />
                <?endif;?>
          </div>
          <span class="demo-widget-header__title">Чат с врачом</span>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-widget-body">
          <div id="chatbot">
            <div id="chatbot-message">
              <p class="from-bot"><span class="user">Врач: </span>Здравствуйте! Как Вас зовут?</p>
            </div>
            <form action="test4.php" method="post" id="chatForm" name="chatForm">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="chatbot-input" type="text" name="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сообщение и нажмите Enter..." autocomplete="off" required>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <input id="chatbot-submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- .input-group -->
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- #chatbot -->
        </div>
        <!-- .demo-widget-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- #demo -->
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
  </div>
  <!-- #main-demo-body -->
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) {

      var messages = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('chatbot-message').querySelectorAll('.from-user'));
      var lastMsg = document.getElementById('chatbot-input').value;
      var filteredMessages = messages.map(
        (msgBlock) => {
          return msgBlock.textContent.replace('Вы: ', '')
        })
      console.log(filteredMessages);
      console.log(lastMsg);

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: JSON.stringify(filteredMessages + ' , ' + lastMsg)
          //            data: $("#" + formData).serialize()
          //            success: function(res) {
          //                alert(res);
          //            }

        //            success: function(response) {
        //                document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response;
        //            },
        //            error: function(response) {
        //                document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "<p>Возникла ошибка при отправке формы. Попробуйте еще раз</p>";
        //            }
      });
    }

    $("#chatbot-submit").click(
      function() {
        AjaxFormRequest(formData, url);
        return false;
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: и где же в вызове AjaxFormRequest(formData, url) урл скрипта? что идет вторым аргументом? какие данные?

Comment: @Jean-Claude - а что идет первым аргументом, Вам понятно?

Comment: первый аргумент насколько я понимаю данные формы, но мне необходимо передавать массив json, состоящий из собранных строк по getElementsByClassName (ответы юзера), это всё, что мне необходимо передавать

Comment: @Igor а Вам, разве, непонятно?

Comment: @Jean-Claude - теперь - непонятно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551649/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/551959?noredirect=1#comment709861_551959

Comment: @Igor в данном топике разместил весь код целиком, потому как в том, на который Вы ссылаетесь не достаточно информативно описал всю ситуацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#chatbot-submit").click(
    function () {
        AjaxFormRequest(null, $("#chatForm").attr("action"));
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: после сабмита формы попап закрывается. как можно избежать этого?

Comment: сменить тип кнопки на `button`, либо сделать `preventDefault`.

Comment: @Arnial сделал,что посоветовали, теперь сообщения не перемещаются из инпута в окно переписки, а остаются в нём